# How does one make AdoptOpenJDK 11 work with Eclipse Oxygen and JavaFX 11

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx

I am on a Mac running Mojave 10.14.4. I have downloaded and installed AdoptOpenJDK (OpenJDK 11 LTS) and tried to access it with Eclipse Oxygen IDE so I can use it with JavaFX 11 instead of the JavaFX that comes with the currently installed Java SE 10. What do I do?

I had tried copying the path and filename to the installation in the "Edit JRE" dialogue in Eclipse with no success. My Eclipse is Oxygen.3a Release (4.7.3a)
Build id: 20180405-1200

I expect to see the new JDK listed in the Eclipse window showing installed JREs. I want to use the open source JDK instead of Oracle's.

If I run a sample program with the current set up it runs without some GUI elements and shows this error: WARNING: Loading FXML document with JavaFX API of version 11.0.1 by JavaFX runtime of version 10.0.1

Comment: If you do not have a compelling reason to have several JDKs installed on your machine, I suggest removing all but the desired one, which in your case appears to be JDK 11. Also, do you have environment variable JAVA_HOME defined? If yes, what is its value?

Comment: What "path and filename" were you copying?

Comment: Thanks, I resolved the issue by falling back on JDK 8 and opting for NetBeans 8.2. Mohave also has its issues and I decided to rollback to High Sierra and everythings fine